# GWT Generator sequencing

Tags: java, gwt, generator

If I am using GWT Generator framework to generate source code, how do I ensure that one generator runs before another.

e.g., if I am generating uibinder code, how do I ensure my generator runs before uibinder's?

Comment: Could you give an example? generators run on GWT.create(), so having one generator generate GWT.create() will call the other generator. If a generator depends on some other code being generated by another generator, I thing you have a problem; refactor your code so that both generators might generate the common code, instead of relying on ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to ensure it. Generators works in following way.
When generate method is invoked, generator may return the name of new class and create a new source. After this GWT will try to precompile newly created source. If new class contains GWT.create, which rebinds to some generator, this generator will be invoked as well.

E.g. in your case, your generator will have to create one java class(with normal uibinder stuff) and *.ui.xml file. When GWT will start precompiling newly created class it will invoke UiBinder generator in the end.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the your generator classes must be compiled before other generator triggered classes.

I suggest including generated packages in a dependent Module or simply compiling your generated class files prior to your uibinder files.

In your example, MyGenerator.java would precede MyView.java in the compiler phase.